# Bios does not load, system boots normally after changing time settings

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-8.1, bios, grub

I am very confused by this. I have a CyberpowerPC laptop (Intel HM87 main-board) with dualboot (Win 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04, both 64 bit). I had the dualboot time difference problem many people have, so I loaded my BIOS and set the system time manually to see what that would do.
The system still works like a charm (on boot up I get the splash screen followed the GRUB window, can choose the OS, both of them load normally and work) but when I try to access my BIOS now, it opens a black screen with a white underscore somewhere in the middle of the screen and that's it. The same happens, when i try to access the "select boot device" menu so I can't even load up a live system and run over the hard disk to see if that would fix anything.

Oh yeah, I disabled secure boot some time ago (not very smart maybe), but that did not affect anything as far as I can tell, I was still able to access my BIOS afterwards.

I'm absolutely puzzled by this and have no idea what to do but at least both OS agree on the time now, which is nice I guess :-).

EDIT: Is there really nobody who has any idea how to fix this issue? So far I tried a BIOS reset but that did not help. I am in contact with the manufacturer, but tech support is slow as always.

Is it possible for this problem to be caused by Windows? With the new UEFI systems Windows seems to be working a lot closer to the BIOS than before.

Comment: if you can update your laptop's bios, maybe that will fix the problem.

Comment: @niceman Hm I guess I would have to get a new BIOS from the manufacturer?

Comment: if it is hard and time wasting then wait, I'm sorry as I'm not laptops expert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so reflashing the BIOS solved the problem. I am still clueless as to what caused it in the first place. It seems like somehow the BIOS was corrupted by the dualboot system if that is even possible.

Comment: Just a random corruption, it happens: cosmic rays etc.

Comment: Hm...interesting thought. Have you ever experienced anything like that? That is not very common, is it?